# How to avoid the error empty variable name in Makefile

Tags: linux, make

Whenever I mention any version along with the execution command of this makefile that version should be stored in the variable VERSION, if no version is mentioned the default value should be taken.

This is my Makefile

```
export $(BUILDVERSION) = $2
VERS = VABCDE.00.00A002

$(info    BUILDVERSION is "$(BUILDVERSION)")
$(info    vers is "$(VERS)")
ifneq ($(BUILDVERSION),undefined)
        VERSION := $(VERS)
endif

ifneq ($(BUILDVERSION),undefined)
        VERSION := $(BUILDVERSION)
endif
$(info    VERSION is $(VERSION))
```

CASE 1: I'm getting this output when I include argument for execution

```
BUILDVERSION is "VABCDE.00.00A001"
vers is VABCDE.00.00A002
VERSION is "VABCDE.00.00A001"
```

CASE 2: I'm getting this error when I do not include argument for execution

```
Makefile:1: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
Makefile:1: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
```

Could anyone please help me find what's wrong with my code!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show how you are invoking `make`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I understand the question.

If you task is to provide a version number from outside of `make` and use default value if no version was supplied in the command line. Then the `makefile` should look like this:

```
VERS = VABCDE.00.00A002

$(info    BUILDVERSION is "$(BUILDVERSION)")
$(info    vers is "$(VERS)")

ifdef BUILDVERSION
        VERSION := $(BUILDVERSION)
else
        VERSION := $(VERS)
endif

$(info    VERSION is $(VERSION))
```

And you would call it with:

```
make BUILDVERSION="not-default-version"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export $(BUILDVERSION) = $2
```

tl;dr; GNU make is not bash.

The `$(BUILDVERSION)` would only expand to anything at all if you invoked `make` as `make BUILDVERSION=something`, which will cause that line to a) define `something` as a *function-like macro* which will expand to its second argument when used as `$(call something, ...)`, and b) export an *empty* environment variable named `something` to the commands run from make rules.

If `BUILDVERSION` is not defined or is defined to an empty string, you will get that `empty variable name` error.

```
$ make -f - <<'EOT' BUILDVERSION=something
export $(BUILDVERSION) = $2
all:; set | grep ^something; echo XXX $(call something,first,second)
EOT

set | grep ^something; echo XXX second
something=''
XXX second
```

`$2` does **not** expand to the second argument passed on the command line of make, because ... make is not bash.